# Recompiling Android Launcher2 (Gingerbread)

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to recompile the Launcher2 (Gingerbread) application, so that i can modify it.

However, I get a fair few errors (120ish), namely:

mLeft, mTop, mBottom, mRight, mParent, mContext cannot be resolved to a variable.

These come from (what I can see anyway), private members of the "TextView" widget.

Is there any way to access these private members, or would I need to do some other magic to get this working?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These refer to private/protected members of the `View` and related classes. Lots of them have getters/setters, for instance all of the above (if they are just getting the value) could be replaced with the

`getLeft()`, `getTop()`, `getBottom()`, `getRight()` and `getContext()`

methods of the View class.

Some of them though, may not have public ways to access them. In that case you can either:

- Copy the relevant classes into your project and change the visibility of the members
- Use reflection (ugly, may break) to modify private fields of other classes.

Comment: Fantastic, eclipse didnt show these up in the autocomplete. And I got it built and working on my device - so much for a first ever android app! :-)

Cheers!

Comment: @Marineio Were you able to compile that? Along with all the missing variables, I had issues where Eclipse cannot find android.app.StatusBarManager, android.renderscript.SimpleMesh and so on

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile Launcher2 except as part of a full firmware build, most likely.